# Deadlock on Two Phase Locking transaction

Tags: database, transactions, locking, deadlock

Two Phase Locking can upgrade the lock during locking phase. But I don't know why the following example said that T1 and T2 are deadlock. Why the read_lock(x) cannot upgrade to write_lock(x)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T1 and T2 are processes that are *totally* distinct, *totally unaware* of each other, and so they *should* be.

Even if the T2 process *would* "upgrade its read lock on X" it still wouldn't make any difference about what should happen to T1 : it still should start waiting until the T2 lock on X is released.

So we still have T1 waiting for T2, and we still have T2 *having to* start waiting for T1 at the point where T2 attempts to acquire its lock on Y.

So we still have both processes waiting for the other to release some lock.  Deadlock.

EDIT

Perhaps understanding the issue is a bit easier if you draw in a third component "Locks Manager" that talks to both T1 and T2.  The states that this Locks Manager component goes through are, in order, "No locks", "Read lock held by T1 on Y", "Read lock held by T1 on Y and Read lock held by T2 on X".

It is the latter bit that first forces the Lock Manager into denying the lock request by T1 on X, and the former bit that subsequently forces the Lock Manager into denying the lock request by T2 on Y.